# Hover and clearTimeout doesn't seem to be working with Cloud Zoom

Tags: jquery, hover, settimeout

I'm trying to trigger an event only after the mouse is over a certain div for 2 seconds. If the mouse goes out of the div then nothing is supposed to happen. Right now what it does is that when I move my mouse over the div and move it away it still triggers the event but it shouldn't.

Here's what I wrote:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var timer;
    $('.image_wrapper').hover(function() {
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
            alert('This is my event');
       }, 2000);
    }, 
    function () {
        clearTimeout(timer);
    });
});
```

Any idea?

Thanks!

**EDIT**
The problem is with the Cloud Zoom used at the same time. If you add the following line below the code with the Cloud Zoom plugin, you will be able to reproduce the issue:

```
$('.cloud-zoom, .cloud-zoom-gallery').CloudZoom();
```

Comment: Can you please provide a http://www.jsfiddle.net with your relevant problematic code?

Comment: I have try and it works (http://jsfiddle.net/V5suj/)

Comment: you should do a jsFiddle whit you html, css etc. if it still not works.. we can help..

Comment: Actually it does work like Fab Sa says. I just found out it doesn't work when the Zoom Cloud plugin is included on the page:
http://code.google.com/p/endcms/source/browse/trunk/2010/end_www/view/default/js/cloud-zoom.1.0.2.js?r=131